# updated UI not showing before sync ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, asynchronous

I Have a 2 JavaScript functions what call one after another. like following.

```
updateUI(event);
syncCall();

function updateUI(event) {
  formSubmitBtn = $(event.target).find('[type=submit]:not(".disabled")');
  formSubmitBtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var loadingText = I18n.t('Submitting');
  formSubmitBtn.val(loadingText).text(loadingText);
}

function syncCall(){
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/calls/synccall',
    success: function (json) {
      userIsSignedIn = json.is_signed_in;
    }
  });
}
```

I am updating a UI element before sync ajax call. but UI changes are not showing. When I try to debug the code it works fine.

Comment: try making the `syncCall` asynchronous ... `setTimeout(syncCall, 0)` ... see if that helps

Comment: show the code for the functions.

Comment: @JaromandaX not possible to change the call in current scenario.

Comment: Then you have a problem

Comment: Check for an updated UI element before triggering `syncCall()`

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: @YashParekh updated

Comment: @sideroxylon when i comment syncall updateUI works.

Comment: @atulquest93 code added

Comment: why can't the AJAX be asynchronous? seeing as **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.** - which is exactly your problem, detrimental end user experience (bet you get some message like that in the console too)

Comment: @JaromandaX i need that response variable immediately in next line.

Comment: asynchronous code can be daunting, but it's been the way of the future since 1999 - as you haven't shown the next line, it's not obvious that you need the result ... which is available in the success function callback

Comment: Try calling `synCall` from within `updateUI`, after the loading text has been displayed.

Comment: @wasipeer It will not work if its sync call, make it async. did we know what is the problem with async, then we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine your code is doing something like

```
var userIsSignedIn;
updateUI(event);
syncCall();
nextThing(userIsSignedIn);
anotherThing();
moreThings();
```

With a simple change to syncCall - called asyncCall to be not confusing

```
function asyncCall(cb){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/calls/synccall',
        success: function (json) {
          cb(json.is_signed_in);
        }
    });
}
```

your code re-written:

```
updateUI(event);
asyncCall(function(userIsSignedIn) {
    nextThing(userIsSignedIn);
    anotherThing();
    moreThings();
});
```

Note the lack of `var userIsSignedIn;` required

Really a small change for improved end user experience

a second alternative is to wrap all the code you presented in a function tagged `async`

```
async function doThings() {
    updateUI(event);
    let userIsSignedIn = await ajaxCall(); // see below
    nextThing(userIsSignedIn);
    anotherThing();
    moreThings();
}
```

and return a Promise from `ajaxCall` (what was `syncCall`)

```
function ajaxCall(){
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/calls/synccall'
    }).then(json => json.is_signed_in);
}
```

Run this through a transpiler (like babel) to produce code that should work on Internet Exploder and similarly "backward" browsers

Summary: In the end you have two choices

- Use async:false and have rubbish user experience
- embrace asynchrony and write code that befits the 21st century

Answer (score -2):

Call this function beforeSend like as follows

```
function syncCall(){
    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/calls/synccall',
    beforeSend:function(){
        updateUI(event);// Call here 
    }
    success: function (json) {
      userIsSignedIn = json.is_signed_in;
    }
  });
}
```

If above not work try following

```
updateUI(event);

function updateUI(event) {
  formSubmitBtn = $(event.target).find('[type=submit]:not(".disabled")');
  formSubmitBtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var loadingText = I18n.t('Submitting');
  formSubmitBtn.val(loadingText).text(loadingText);
  syncCall();// Try calling here 
}

function syncCall(){
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/calls/synccall',
    success: function (json) {
      userIsSignedIn = json.is_signed_in;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: ui changes not shows but when i execute in the debug mode it works fine. I have did some search and came to know the these is a problem with sync ajax call because it block UI.

Comment: Ohhh here is async is false

Comment: Why async is false

Comment: Remove **async:false**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150683/discussion-between-sourabh-somani-and-wasipeer).

Comment: synchronous xmlhttprequest will always prevent the UI from updating which is why it is deprecated - you can write this in 100 different ways, as long as async:false you won't fix the issue :p

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX I know about that and thanks but I am just saying you can try

Comment: try what? *synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.* No amount of code wrangling will change that simple fact